# Can i IP restrict force.com pages rather than the whole site?

Tags: javascript, force.com, guest-user

I haven't seen this documented anywhere so assuming this might not be doable. But lets say i have a huge force.com site and only want to have a few pages within it that are available to staff only. i do not require them to login to see the pages but i want to ensure that nobody else external would see the content.

Is there a way to use some javascript maybe to identify a guest user's IP and redirect that user promptly to another page if they are not the range of authorised IP's?

if not then i guess i will have to create a second site which is IP restricted and have links to pages within that site from the login enabled site.

Comment: It's possible with JScript: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Comment: hi and thanks for that answer. i had seen it previously but it seemed to pose some issues in terms of security. however that same page does have another less popular solution which i will try to use to create a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the link provided above in the comment is the best candidate for now. closing this question